# This code gives unwanted '0' in output (C++)

Tags: c++, numbers, zero

I was making a program which coverts a list of prime numbers into yes-no format. By yes-no I mean that `2, 3, 5, 7, 11` gets converted into `1101010001` where '0' represents composite number and '1' represents prime number. This means that 2 is prime, 3 is prime, 4 is composite, 5 is prime, 6 is composite and so on. This is my code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
unsigned long long int sti (string inp) //This function just converts string to integer
{
    unsigned long long int size = inp.size();
    unsigned long long int ret = 0 ;
    for (unsigned long long int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ret += pow(10, i) * stoi(to_string(inp[size-i-1]));
    }
    return ret;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream ifs("1.txt");
    string temp = "";
    string ret = "";
    unsigned long long int inp1 = 0;
    unsigned long long int inp2 = 0;
    ifs >> temp;
    inp1 = sti(temp);
    ret+='1';
    int diff=0;
    while(true)
    {
        inp2= inp1;
        ifs >> temp;
        inp1 = sti(temp);
        if(inp1==inp2)
        {
            break;
        }
        diff = inp1-inp2-1;
        for(int i=0; i<diff; i++)
        {
            ret+='0'; 
        }
        ret+='1';
        
    }
    cout<< ret; 
}
```

But when I try to convert first 10 primes, ie - 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29, The code outputs `1101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010001010001000001`

The code gives unexpected zeroes between 7 and 11.
Can anyone please help me with what is happening?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your function `sti` which ends up invoking `stoi`. Why not just... use `stoi`? Seems error-prone, especially since you're introducing floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @NathanPierson but according to my knowledge `stoi` converts just one char at once?

Comment: Your knowledge is wrong. `stoi` converts a _string_ to an integer. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) for instance.

Comment: Thank you @NathanPierson for correcting me

Comment: It also solved my problem.